# Импорт функций из другого файла pytnon

Tags: python

Допустим есть два файла `Main` и `DrawW`. Я хочу обратиться к функции из файла `DrawW`. И все бы ничего, если бы не понадобилось сделать наоборот. Я говорю о том, что если я пропишу следующий код:

В `Main` :

```
from DrawW import *
```

В `DrawW` (потому что надо обратиться к переменным из `Main`) :

```
from main import *
```

то вылетает ошибка:

> NameError: name 'Function' is not defined.

Как можно это исправить, и правильно  ли я вообще делаю?

P.S. :

Логика такова:

- есть переменная `Lose`, указывающая на то, не проиграл ли игрок.
- есть функция `Draw` (которую я хотел бы вынести в отдельный файл). В данной функции работает цикл `if`.

  ```
  if not Lose :
      #в теле указано то, какие .png файлы нужно  отрисовывать
  ```

Загвоздка заключается в том, что `Lose` зависит от других переменных, находящихся в файле Main. И как вы уже указали нельзя использовать 'кольцевой импорт'. Так вот что же посоветуете. Извините что не вставил фрагмент кода.

Comment: Это кольцевой импорт, так делать нельзя

Comment: А как мне это обойти ?

Comment: а зачем вы вообще импортируете что-то из main? Хотелось бы понять вашу логику обмена данными между этими модулями.

Comment: Я использую pygame, и для отрисовки (чтобы не делать все операции в одном файле, т.к. получается уж слишком большой кусок кода ) я решил вынести в отдельный файл. Так вот, я как бы пытаюсь получить доступ к переменной из Main, чтобы дать понять проге, что именно надо рисовать(переменная Lose, указывающая на то, проиграл ли игрок).

Comment: выносите код в модули так, чтобы не нужно было импортировать что-то из main. Можете добавить в вопрос схематичный короткий пример того что вы импортируете, чтобы была понятна ваша логика, и тогда, возможно, вам смогут что-то посоветовать. Сейчас вопрос слишком абстрактный.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант избежать кольцевого импорта - вынести общий для двух модулей функционал в третий модуль. В вашем случае можно вынести переменную lose в отдельный модуль, например "variable.py" и импортировать ее в двух оставшихся модулях.

variable.py

```
lose = False
```

Main.py

```
import Draw
import variable

variable.lose = True
```

Draw.py

```
import variable

if not variable.lose:
```