# Как обратиться к переменной из другого модуля в PYTHON 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули, python-import

У меня есть два файла: *main.py* и *sub.py*

Мне надо завести в *main* переменную, которую я смогу изменять в *sub*. Проблема в том, что *sub* импортируется в *main* и при добавлении строчки `from main import charts` (где **charts** -  нужная мне константа) получается ошибка, как я понимаю, связанная с зацикленным импортом.

Я видел похожий вопрос тут [Импорт функций из другого файла pytnon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090228/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-pytnon), но там всего лишь один ответ, который мне кажется неправильным. Хотелось бы узнать, существуют ли какие-то еще варианты выхода из данной ситуации

UPD.

**main.py**

```
from sub.py import MyClass

charts = 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
   my_example = MyClass()
   my_example.func()
```

**sub.py**

```
class MyClass:
    def func(self):
        // тут надо увеличить charts из main и вывести его
```

Comment: приведите пожалуйста минимальные примеры `main.py` и `sub.py`

Comment: Избавиться от зацикленного импорта, очевидно. Наличие зацикленного импорта с почти стопроцентной вероятностью означает, что вы выбрали неправильную архитектуру

Comment: @S.Nick добавил

Comment: @MarkTiukov во-первых, показанный вами код синтаксически некорректен, а во-вторых, в реальных проектах писать подобным образом нужно примерно никогда. Непонятно, зачем это нужно

Comment: @andreymal то есть Вы хотите сказать, что в питоне так совсем не принято? В других языках (c++ и java) я постоянно обращался к разных константам и прочим вещах в подобных ситуациях. Это удобно и эффективно. Хотелось бы узнать, как такое делать в Python3

Comment: @MarkTiukov даже в c++ и java (особенно в java!) манипуляции глобальными переменными считаются плохим тоном, и опытные коллеги за такой код будут ругать независимо от языка. Как такое делать — не использовать глобальные переменные, в первую очередь.

Comment: @andreymal если вы про слово class, то забыл его, да

Comment: @MarkTiukov а вообще в таком случае достаточно перенести import main внутрь func, чтобы случился отложенный импорт без зацикливания. Но, повторюсь, глобальные переменные это плохо в любом языке, и лучше придумать способ решения задачи без глобальных переменных и без зацикленных импортов вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Можно создать глобальную переменную

*#settings.py*

```
def init():
    global charts
    charts = 10
```

---

*#main.py*

```
import settings
settings.init() #создаем этот вызов один раз при создании программы
print(settings.charts)
```

---

*#sub.py*

```
import settings # везде где они нужны делаем импорт

class MyClass:
    def func(self, charts):
        settings.charts += 1
```

---

**2)** Можно создать используя @property и .setter, и сразу при обновлении переменной выполнять метод

*#settings.py*

```
class Global_Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self._charts = 10        

    @property
    def charts(self):
        print('Произошел запрос переменной')
        return self._charts
    @charts.setter
    def charts(self, value):
        print('Произошло изменение переменной')
        self._charts = value

settings = Global_Settings()
```

---

*#sub.py*

```
from settings import settings

class MyClass:
    def func(self, charts):
        settings.charts += 1
```

---

*#main.py*

```
from settings import settings    
print(settings.charts) #выводим
```

Answer (score 0):

**main.py**

```
#from sub.py import MyClass
from sub import MyClass

charts = 10
print(f'main.py: charts = {charts}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   my_example = MyClass()
   my_example.func(charts)
```

---

**sub.py**

```
class MyClass:

    def func(self, charts):

        # тут надо увеличить charts из main и вывести его

        charts += 1
        print(f'sub.py: charts = {charts}')
```